# Reformat Dates in Perl (for later use in MySQL)

Tags: perl, date, datetime, format

I am writing a Perl script to open a .csv file, make some changes, sort it on four fields, then write it back to a new file.  Found out that because this data will then be used to load a MySQL table that I also need to reformat the Date variables.  Currently, Dates are in the file as 00/00/0000 and for MySQL, need to have them formatted as 0000-00-00.  Right now, I simply tried to do it for one field, although I actually need to do it on three Date fields for each line from the .csv file.

This script is running - but it is not reformatting the Date field I'm trying to test this on.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl/  

use strict;  
use warnings; 
use Data::Dumper; 

#my $filename = '/swpkg/shared/batch_processing/mistints/mistints.csv'; 
my $filename = 'tested.csv'; 

open my $FH, $filename 
  or die "Could not read from $filename <$!>, program halting."; 

# Read the header line.  
chomp(my $line = <$FH>); 
my @fields = split(/,/, $line); 
#print "Field Names:\n", Dumper(@fields), $/; 
print Dumper(@fields), $/;    
my @data; 
    # Read the lines one by one.  
    while($line = <$FH>) { 

    # split the fields, concatenate the first three fields, 
    # and add it to the beginning of each line in the file  
        chomp($line); 
        my @fields = split(/,/, $line); 
        unshift @fields, join '_', @fields[0..2]; 
        push @data, \@fields;
        my $in_date = $fields[14];
        my $db_date = join '-', reverse split /\D/, $in_date;
    } 
    close $FH; 
    print "Unsorted:\n", Dumper(@data); #, $/; 

    @data = sort { 
        $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] || 
        $a->[20] cmp $b->[20] || 
        $a->[23] cmp $b->[23] || 
        $a->[26] cmp $b-> [26] 
    } @data; 


    open my $OFH, '>', '/swpkg/shared/batch_processing/mistints/parsedMistints.csv';
    #print $OFH Dumper(@data);
    print $OFH join(',', @$_), $/ for @data;
    close $OFH;


    #print "Sorted:\n", Dumper(@data); 
    #print "Sorted:", Dumper(@data);

    exit;
```

The two lines I added to this script (which are not working) are the **my $in_date** and **my $db_date** lines. Now I will also need to reformat two fields (at the end of each line) that are DATETIME, i.e. 10/23/2015 10:47, where I will only need to reformat the date within that field, and I'm not even sure where to begin tackling that one.

And please go easy since I'm a noob with Perl.

EDIT - SORRY, had to re-edit because I didn't notice the first part of my script had not copied.

Comment: What do you mean by *not working*? If I set `$in_date` to `01/02/2003` then your formula for `$db_date` gives `2003-02-01` which looks correct. You don't do anything with your `$db_date` value; are you forgetting to put it back into `@fields`?

Comment: Borodin - YES - that was what I was missing - I forgot to move my "push @data, \@fields;" to AFTER I manipulated the data.

I also came up with one line to replace those two lines (and get rid of the variable) -

$fields[14] = join '-', (split m{/}, $fields[14] [2,0,1]);

Now just a test to make sure it's working as I want...

Comment: You should read my answer for a more general solution

Comment: That should be `$fields[14] = join '-', (split /\//, $fields[14])[2,0,1]` or more concisely `$_ = join '-', (split /\//)[2,0,1] for $fields[14]`

Comment: The $_ = join '-', (split /\//)[2,0,1] for $fields[14] line worked for all three fields.  Now just have to see whether Time::Piece is available for me to work with on the DATETIME fields.

Comment: `Time::Piece` has been a core module since Perl v5.10, so unless you are running a very old release it should already be installed. If you want to apply the same transform to multiple fields then you should write `$_ = join '-', (split /\//)[2,0,1] for @fields[14, 15, 16]` substituting the correct indexes, of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a bunch of string functions, it's better to use the [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) module to parse and reformat date-time values. It has `strptime` and `strftime` methods to do this for you. This short program shows the reformatting of both date-time formats that you mention. `ymd` is a convenience method, and is equivalent to `strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece;

my $in_date = '01/02/2003';
my $db_date = Time::Piece->strptime($in_date, '%m/%d/%Y')->ymd;
say "$in_date -> $db_date";

$in_date = '01/02/2003 04:05';
$db_date = Time::Piece->strptime($in_date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M');
say "$in_date -> $db_date";
```

#### output

```
01/02/2003 -> 2003-02-01
01/02/2003 04:05 -> 2003-02-01 04:05
```

---

#### Update

If you prefer, you could write a subroutine that takes the original date and its format string, together with the desired format. Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece;

my $in_date = '01/02/2003';
my $db_date = date_from_to($in_date, '%m/%d/%Y', '%Y-%m-%d');
say "$in_date -> $db_date";

$in_date = '01/02/2003 04:05';
$db_date = date_from_to($in_date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M');
say "$in_date -> $db_date";

sub date_from_to {
    my ($date, $from, $to) = @_;
    Time::Piece->strptime($date, $from)->strftime($to);
}
```

The output is identical to that of the program above

---

#### Update

Regarding your comment, your code should look like this

```
$_ = join '-', (split /\//)[2,0,1] for $fields[14, 20, 23];

$_ = Time::Piece->strptime($_,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') for @fields[38,39];

push @data, \@fields;
```

But I would prefer to see some consistency in the way the date fields are handled, like this

```
$_ = Time::Piece->strptime($_, '%m/%d/%Y')->strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for @fields[14,20,23];

$_ = Time::Piece->strptime($_, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') for @fields[38,39];

push @data, \@fields
```

Comment: See above - you were right - I forgot to move the push @data line to after I was finished manipulating the data.

I will also try Time::Piece: for manipulating the DATETIME fields as you have demonstrated here.

Comment: I tried this section below
    `$_ = join '-', (split /\//)[2,0,1] for $fields[14];
    $_ = join '-', (split /\//)[2,0,1] for $fields[20];
    $_ = join '-', (split /\//)[2,0,1] for $fields[23];`

which worked, but
`$_ = Time::Piece->strptime($fields[38],'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M');
    $_ = Time::Piece->strptime($fields[39],'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M');
    push @data, \@fields;`

...did not change the dates in the DATETIME fields.